# Why does GetServerVariable("HTTP_URL") return different value depending on the pipeline mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

In IIS, why does calling `GetServerVariable("HTTP_URL")` of the `HttpWorkerRequest` class result in different values depending on the pipeline mode?

When running under **Integrated mode**, it returns the raw url (that the server sees e.g, "/SomeUrl/Default.ashx").

While under **Classic mode** it seems like the value is the url that was typed into the browser (my url router maps for example /someurl to that specific handler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this. Turns out we were doing a `HttpContext.RewritePath` which (I think) changes the result of `GetServerVariable("HTTP_URL")` under **Integrated Mode**. We replaced this by newing up the corresponding `IHttpHandler` and invoking it, instead of rewriting the path.